# could not convert string to float: '[' - Unsure why i'm getting this message. - Python

Tags: python, csv

So firstly my code wasn't working because i was multiply a string, and obviously you can't do that. I then changed "a" into a float when the average is being printed. However now i am getting this error and i'm really not sure. This code for background information is pulling data out of a CSV file with scores in 3 columns and i'm trying to find the average. However CSV files are all strings and you cannot have integers as values in a CSV file. So any help would be much appreciated.

this is my csv file:
callum,2,0,2

this is my code:

```
            with open("Class1.csv") as f:
                columns = f.readline().strip().split(" ")
                numRows = 0
                sums = [1] * len(columns)

                for line in f:
                # Skip empty lines
                    if not line.strip():
                        continue

                values = line.split(" ")
                for i in range(1,len(values)):

                    sums[i] += int(values[i])
                    numRows += 1

                for index, a in enumerate (str(sums)):
                    print (columns[index], 1.0 * float(a) / numRows)
```

Comment: `a` is a `'['` somewhere, and that can't be converted into a `float`. Check your input file. Also, you can indeed multiply a string: `'ab'*3 == 'ababab'`.

Comment: Share the contents of a csv file which produces this error but shouldn't in your post.

Comment: what is the answer to `float("[")` ?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thankyou, i shall check and also i'm aware of that but you if you multiply the string '5' by 2 that is '55' not 10 which is what i'm looking for.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare it's simply one row of callum,2,0,2

Comment: @JoranBeasley i'm not quite sure what you mean..

Comment: [Python has a builtin csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), use that for dealing with csv files. Your actual problem here is however that you iterate over `str(sums)` which produces a string representation of the list, e.g. a string like `"[1,2,3]"`. That simply makes no sense, you probably just want to iterate over the individual items instead.

Comment: @l4mpi Interesting, i'll try this but i don't think this will be the solution, honestly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at `float(a)`, I can see that `a` relates to `str(sums)`.  Looking up further, `sums` is a list containing the integer 1 repeated.  So:

```
>>> sums = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> d = str(sums)
>>> d
'[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]'
>>> type(d)
<type 'str'>
>>> d[0]
'['
>>> float(d[0])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    float(d[0])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: [
```

The problem is that you're doing `str(sums)` which gives you a string containing string-character representations of the list structure... including the `[]` used to indicate a list.  That's why you're getting an error.

Finally, note that while Python is dynamically typed, it is also *strongly* typed.  It won't do implicit type conversion for something like `'5' * 2`.  You must explicitly make the string value an integer before attempting multiplication.